# how to remove characters from a font file?

Tags: unicode, font-face, webfonts

i've downloaded the [DejaVu open source font](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dejavu/) and want to use it ad a WebFont, but even when converting it, i get a large file, and because the website i'll use will be only in few languages (arabic, french, amazigh) then, i dont need some characters.

so is there a way to browse the font file and delete the unnecessary range of unicode characters that i'll not need?

Comment: Answers are probably all there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557944/downsizing-an-otf-font-by-removing-glyphs

Answer (score 19):

Using [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/), you may open `Element`->`Font Info`->`Unicode Ranges`. You will see all available ranges and you can select a whole Unicode range with a single click. Then, you can tune your selection and delete using `Encoding`->`Detach & Remove Glyphs`.

Also, you can use `Edit`->`Select`->`Select by Script`.

To create a new font from the minified or reduced glyph set, `File`->`Generate Fonts...`, then choose a font file type in the dropdown menu under the filename field, and then click `Generate`.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest method I found is to use `pyftsubset` tool from [FontTools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FontTools). Here's an example:

```
$ pyftsubset NotoSans-Regular.ttf \
      --unicodes=U+0400-045F,U+0490-0491,U+04B0-04B1,U+2116 \
      --output-file=NotoSans-Regular.cyrillic.woff2 \
      --flavor=woff2
```

Note: `woff2` output requires [Brotli](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Brotli).

I wrote a simple script around it which automates the whole process including generation of a CSS file after splitting the font file. You may find it here: https://github.com/johncf/ttf2web

Comment: For anyone wondering, this also worked with an OTF font for me.