# Tools/scripts for editing and removing glyphs from .ttf files

Tags: truetype

I have some .ttf files I am using for an embedded project and I would like to reduce their filesizes. I don't have any experience working with font's other than mapping the files to this library I'm using. Basically I would like the fonts to only contain latin characters, any recommended tools for doing this? Ideally, something that I could script or configure so that I could process multiple .ttf files

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557944/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who's interested, FontForge made this really easy