# Arabic numbers with ar-ae and ar-sa locale in Android

Tags: android, locale, arabic

As I asked in the following question:

[Arabic number in Arabic text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266789/arabic-number-in-arabic-text-in-android)

if I use the arabic locale ar-ae or ar-sa the numbers are shown using Hindu-Arabic numbers.
I need to show the digits like in English: "1234567890".

I used to use the trick of setting the numeral extension

```
Locale.Builder builder = new Locale.Builder();
builder.setLocale(savedLocale).setExtension(Locale.UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION, "nu-latn");
Locale locale = builder.build();
```

The problem is that after you do that the resource lookup gets broken and with Nougat it just does not work anymore.

Is there a way to see the "normal" digits even using the Arabic locale for ae and sa?

Comment: One workaround is to replace the font for the digit characters. You'll be able to keep your original font for the text.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin if you put it as an answer I'll set is as correct

Comment: I just posted it. Let me know if you need some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to replace the font for the digit characters. You'll be able to keep your original font for the text.

I would recommend to do that in a clean way by extending [TypeFaceSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-a-custom-typeface).
Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675070/multiple-typeface-in-single-textview).

If you need some code, let me know and I'll update this answer.

Comment: Do you mean that I would need to set two different spans everytime I write numbers? In that case it would be simpler to use String.valueOf() and convert the number in an ASCII string

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure I've understood what you mean. In the linked question the idea is to use CustomTypefaceSpan to set a different font in two different spans

Comment: please see also the other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744973/987753

Answer (score 1):

For now what I did is to use a custom font and to replace in the file for the custom font the digits with the Hindu-Arabic numbers with the correspondent char for the "western-Arabic" number.

Please check
[how to remove characters from a font file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976424/how-to-remove-characters-from-a-font-file)

**EDIT**

It is now possible to use a locale like for example:

```
<item>ar-AE-u-nu-latn</item> <!-- Arabic (United Arab Emirates, Western Digits) -->
```

This is taken from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/locale_config.xml)

Answer (score 1):

You should trust the locale you are using. If you are specifically targetting ar_SA then you should let it render things the way it's meant to for that country. If you just want Arabic language but want the western Arabic numbers then try a locale from one of the western Arab countries, ar_MA for example.